# ios Google SignIn integration doesn't logout from application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-signin

i 've integrated Google SignIn in my ios application manually referring link [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating] and it works good for login but its logout method doesn't seems to work it caches user credentials entered initially.i want to show signin screen every time when user hits the signin button(customised button).i've tried clear cookies ,credentials but nothing seems to work.where it store credentials because when opening google login page on safari outside the application it prompts for credentials.how can i logout from application any help please?

```
   @IBAction func googlePlusButtonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject)
   {
   let file =  NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GoogleService-Info", ofType: ".plist")
    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary.init(contentsOfFile: file!)
     if let clientID = dictionary!["CLIENT_ID"]
     {

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = clientID as! String
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

}

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user:     GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!)
{

    if error == nil
    {
        let userId = user.userID
        let tokenId = user.authentication.idToken
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let email = user.profile.email
        print("Welcome: ,\(userId), \(tokenId), \(fullName), \(givenName),\(email)")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
    }
    else
    {
        //show message for user cancelled sign in
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

Comment: did you implemented "didDisconnectWithError", If not then please implement, and if it is not getting logged out then it will show the error in this method.

Comment: @Wolverine, didDisconnectWithError is already implemented and its not showing any error.

Comment: did you set anywhere "trySilentAuthentication" in your code ?

Comment: Normally GPP library will save user credentials in Keychain, so next time it is not asking for login again. instead of that it will login silently.

Comment: You can check this by GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() it will return TRUE if Auth is already stored or FALSE if not stored.

Comment: set flag in useDefault and check for this value and decide which screen you want to open

Comment: GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() returns false but still it redirects to permission page not to SignIn.

Comment: Hello Nitisha, did you find an answer?

Comment: @Emanuel - no i cannot find

Comment: Has anyone found an answer for this yet? Still facing the same issue, logout and disconnect both fail to work. I've also tried refreshing the tokens, using GTMAppAuth etc. It's adamant that it's going to use cookies or some stored auth which I can't seem to clear.

Comment: Just FYI there's a bug raised here but no response:
https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/326

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func Google_Login_Clicked(sender: AnyObject)
{
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When you want to google logout write below code.

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()